# Irc chat channel to supplement the beta

Tags: discussion, chat

Having a chat channel wouldn't scale ultimately, but I wouldn't mind chatting about tangentially related subjects to the questions. Does anyone else have interest in setting up and Irc channel. I have no idea how to do it, but found the #haskell channel very informative, and definitely has help create a sense of community.

Comment: The stack exchange team already has a chat client in the works.

Comment: @John But it won't be in operation for another 6-8 weeks, according to the site.

Comment: Don't worry about scaling. Stackoverflow had an IRC channel for meta discussion too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone ahead and registered the **#mathexchange** channel over on Freenode (irc.freenode.net).

It's set up and ready to go... I'll probably be idling there while things get going. Feel free to start using it whenever! Only suggestion is that people use their StackExchange usernames as nicknames.

Comment: I am fpqc.  This is clear from my userpic.

Answer (score 3):

For info, chat.stackexchange is now open; please feel free to drop by - see the "chat" link at the top of all pages on the main Q&A site.